# Passing char* to atoi

Tags: c, type-conversion, c-strings, unsigned-integer, atoi

Here's the scenrio -

```
        #include <stdio.h>
        #include <stdlib.h>
        #include <stdint.h>

        int main()
        {
            uint8_t backoff;
            char* value = "300000";
            backoff=atoi(value);
            printf("value = %s\n", value);
            printf("backoff value = %d\n", backoff);

            return (0);
        }
```

Output is as -

```
        value = 300000
        backoff value = 224
```

Can someone please help me understand how this conversion happened ?

Comment: 300000 won't fit in `uint8_t`.

Comment: 300000 == 0x493e0.  224 == 0xe0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pretty simple.  Values of uint8_t are 0 to 255.  You need at least uint32_t (uint16_t max 65535).  224 is the bits of the real answer that fit in the 8 bit int.